# Unity point light use 2x draw calls

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a game and I have a particle system which emits light (I am using a point light). Particle system is limited to 36 particles and Profiler shows me that I have 2x draw calls compared to my particles amount (72 draw calls and 72 setpass calls). I am using Deferred rendering path. Why is this happening? How to decrease draw calls?

Comment: probably because they emit light light bouncing around has to be calculated

Comment: So there is no way to use 1 draw call for a particle?

Comment: do the particles themselves need to be lit? you can use an unlit shader